# Performance issues with EmberJS and Rails 4 API

Tags: javascript, sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, ember.js

I have an EmberJS application which is powered by a Rails 4 REST API. The application works fine the way it is, however it is becoming very sluggish based on the kind of queries that are being performed.

Currently the API output is as follows:

```
"projects": [{
    "id": 1,
    "builds": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}]
```

The problem arises when a user has lots of projects with lots of builds split between them. EmberJS currently looks at `builds` key then makes a request to `/builds?ids[]=1&ids[]=2` which is the kind of behaviour I want.

This question could have one of two solutions.

1. Update Rails to load the build_ids more efficiently
2. Update EmberJS to support different queries for builds

### Option 1: Update Rails

I have tried various solutions regarding eager loading and manually grabbing the IDs using custom methods on the serializer. Both of these solution add a lot of extra code that I'd rather not do and still do individual queries per project.

By default rails also does `SELECT *` style queries when doing **has_many** and I can't figure out how to overwrite this at the serializer layer. I also wrote a horrible solution which got the entire thing to one fast query but it involved writing raw SQL which I know isn't the Rails way of doing things and I'd rather not have such a huge complex untestable query as the default scope.

### Option 2: Make Ember use different queries

Instead of requesting `/builds?ids[]=1&ids[]=2` I would rather not include the builds key at all on the project and make a request to `/builds?project_id=1` when I access that variable within Ember. I think I can do this manually on a per field basis by using something similar to this:

```
builds: function () {
    return this.store.find('builds', { project_id: this.get('id') });
}.property()
```

instead of the current:

```
builds: DS.hasMany('build', { async: true })
```

It's also worth mentioning that this doesn't only apply to "builds". There are 4 other keys on the project object that do the same thing so that's 4 queries per project.

Comment: I'm of the opinion of using the ORM where ever possible. But where necessary overwrite with raw SQL. Active record is so convenient, but also so slow. Some info on your DB could help, is it MySQL? What are the indexes like on your pivot/join tables?

Comment: Has this quesiton been asnwered by alex well enough Marc? Could you please select the answer? How did you go with this? Keen to know :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you made sure that you have properly added indexes to your database? Adding and index on the builds table on `project_id` will make it work a lot faster.

Alternatively you should use the links attribute to load your records.

```
{"projects": [{
    "id": 1,
    "links": {
      "builds": "/projects/1/builds"
    }
}]}
```

This means that the builds table will only be queried when the relationships is accessed.

Comment: Yes I have indexes but the database is being accessed across a WAN currently. Does EmberJS understand the "links" attribute? I would love to use this syntax: http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-url-template-shorthands. I am currently solving this using option 2 as I mentioned above which is not ideal synatx but achieves the same as what you're suggesting. If ember could do this Internally that would be perfect.

Comment: Ember supports this natively

Answer (score 2):

Things you can try:

- Make sure your rails controller only selects the columns needed for JSON serialization.
- Ensure you have indexes on the columns present in your where and join clauses unless the column is boolean or has low number of distinct values.  Always ensure you have indexes on foreign key columns.
- Be VERY VERY careful with how you are using ActiveRecord `joins` vs `includes` vs `preload` vs `eager` and `references`. This area is fraught with problems composing scopes together and subtle things can alter the SQL generated and number of queries issued and even what actual results are returned. I noticed differences in minor point releases of AR 4 yielding different query results because of the join strategy AR would choose.
- Often you want to aim to reduce the number of SQL's issued to the database but joining tables is not always the best solution. You will need to benchmark and use EXPLAIN to see what works better for your queries. Sometimes sub queries/sub-selects can be more efficient.
- Querying by parent_id is a good option if you can get Ember Data to perform the request that way as the database has a simpler query.
- You could consider using Ember-Model instead of Ember-Data, I am using it currently as its much simpler and easier to adapt to my needs, and supports multi-fetch to avoid 1+N request problems.
- You may be able to use embedded models or side-loaded models so your server can reduce the number of web requests AND the number of SQLs and return what the client needs in one request / one SQL. Ember-Model supports both embedded and side-loaded models, so Ember-Data being more ambitious may also.
- Although it appears from your question that Ember-Data is doing a multi-fetch, make sure you are doing SQL IN clause for those ID's instead of separate queries.
- Make sure that the SQL on your rails side is not fanning out in a 1+N pattern.  Using the `includes` options to effect eager loading on AR relations may help avoid 1+N queries or it may unnecessarily load models depending on the results needed in your response.
- I also found that the Ruby JSON serializer libraries are less than optimal.  I created a gem [ToJson](https://github.com/ahacking/to_json) that speeds up JSON serializing many times over the existing solutions. You can try it and benchmark for yourself.

I found that ActiveRecord (including AR 4) didn't work well for me and I moved to [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) in the end because it gave me so much more control over join types, join conditions, and query composition and tactical eager loading, plus it was just faster, has wider support for standard SQL features and excellent support for postgres features and extensions. These things can make a huge difference to the way you design your database schema and the performance and types of queries you can achieve.

Using [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) and [ToJson](https://github.com/ahacking/to_json) I can serve around 30-50 times more requests than I could with ActiveRecord + JBuilder for most of my queries, and in some instances its hundreds times better than what I was achieving with AR (especially creates/updates). Besides Sequel being faster at instantiating models from the DB, it also has a Postgres streaming adapter which makes it even faster again for large results.

Changing your data access/ORM layer and JSON serialisation can achieve 30-50 times faster performance or alternatively require managing 30-50 less servers for the same load. It's nothing to sneeze at.